# Vagrant up when opening project in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, vagrant, phpstorm

Is there a way to automatically run `vagrant up` when I open up a project in PhpStorm?

(*and may a `vagrant halt` when closing the project*)

I tried to add a task, what actually only runs external programms or tools. My thought was to call a shell-script. But I would prefer to keep this all in PhpStorm and seeking for a possibility to handle all this inside of PhpStorm.

Comment: Only built-in [Startup Tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/startup-tasks.html) .. which is any Run/Debug Configuration .. which in your case means that you have to create some npm/gulp/grunt task or some another supported configuration in order to be able to run it this way. No closing tasks. Related: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11227 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12334 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5622

Answer (score 0):

In PHPStorm :

1. CTRL + SHIFT + A.
2. Startup Tasks.
3. in the bottom left corner click on + icon.
4. Add configuration.
5. Add shell script.

now you can either enter the content of the command in that case 'vagrant up' or create a .sh file and put the path of it in the path section.

now each time you'll open PHPStorm on this project, your VM will boot up.